# Primefaces blocks component only once

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I need to block datatable when it's updating via ajax. I used blockUI component and it's show() and hide() methods. But it works only once! Where can be the problem? Thanks for help.
Here is part of code:

```
<p:dialog resizable="false" showHeader="false" modal="false"
          widgetVar="statusDialog" draggable="false" closable="false">
  ...
</p:dialog>
<p:panel>
 <p:selectOneMenu id="source" value="#{mainBean.selectedSource}">
   ....
   <p:ajax onstart="statusDialog.show(); feedBlock.show()" 
           oncomplete="statusDialog.hide(); feedBlock.hide()" 
           update="feed" listener="#{mainBean.filter(selectedSource, false)}"/>
 </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:panel>
...
<p:dataTable id="feed" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="460" 
             value="#{mainBean.feed}" var="curr">
  ...
</p:dataTable>
<p:blockUI block="feed" widgetVar="feedBlock"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<p:blockUI block="feed" trigger="source"/>
```

and remove `feedBlock.show()` and `feedBlock.hide()` from `p:ajax`

you might need to change `trigger="source"` into `trigger="myform:source"` etc...

Comment: Thank you. I solved this issue by overriding css class of overlay. So, in p:dialog I changed attribute "modal" to true and then see my custom overlay with desired position, height and width. I think this will work only if we have only one area to block, but this is enough for me.